# Partial F-Test Assumptions

Tags: regression, inference, least-squares, linear-model, normality-assumption

I have a question regarding the underlying assumptions of the partial F-test to compare two regression models:

To use the partial F-test, is it sufficient to assume that the assumptions of the normal linear model hold for the "full" model, or do we have to assume that these hold for the reduced model as well?

My intuition tells me that it should suffice if these conditions hold for the full model, because then we know the distribution of all regression coefficients individually, and so we should be able to test if a subset of these is collectively zero.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Since the probability values needed for the test are calculated under the reduced model, you only need to assume the assumptions are true for that model.  On the other hand, if you want to perform power analysis, you will have to make some assumptions about the full model as well.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in the comments by BigBendRegion:

> Since the probability values needed for the test are calculated under the reduced model, you only need to assume the assumptions are true for that model. On the other hand, if you want to perform power analysis, you will have to make some assumptions about the full model as well.